# What is the difference between the values of these two char arrays?

Tags: c, floating-point, gtk, gtk3

I'm working on code in C that reads the temperature and sends it to a GUI made with GTK3.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char Vo[10];         // voltage out
float Ro, R1 = 6247; // value of resistance at 20C in the thermistor
float T0 = 298.15;   // 25 degrees C in Kelvin
float logR2, R2, T;
float A = 1.281426510e-03, B = 2.368116050e-04, C = 0.9002008458e-07;  // Steinhart-Hart and Hart Coefficients

char *senseTemp() {
    FILE *fp;
    char command[50];
    int c;

    //get the Analog value
    fp = fopen("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error: ");
        return (1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c ", c);
        if (c != EOF) {
            Vo[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    
    //printf("Analog Reading: %s\n", Vo);
    
    //convert the value to resistance
    int V = 0;
    float Vout = 0;
    V = atoi(Vo);           //TO convert an array to an integer
    //printf("Value of V: %d\n", V);
    
    Vout = V * (1.8 / 4095.0);      //Voltage out of the thermistor
    //printf("Voltage out from thermistor: %f\n", Vout);
    
    R2 = R1 * ((1.8 / Vout) - 1);
    
    logR2 = log(R2);
    T = (1.0 / (A + B * logR2 + C * logR2 * logR2 * logR2));  // Steinhart and Hart Equation. T  = 1 / {A + B[ln(R)] + C[ln(R)]^3}
    
    T =  T - 273.15;
    
    char Tfinal[10];
    i = 0;
    
    snprintf(Tfinal, 10, "%.0f", T);
    printf("Here is the value: %s\n", Tfinal);
    
    return Tfinal;
}
```

If I use `return Vo;` the values are properly returned to the GUI and I can see them, but I want to convert the values to degrees celsius and that is what the variable T holds. But the `gtk_label_set_text()` that displays the temperature in the GUI only takes a pointer to a string.

So in my code if I use `return Vo` it works but not with `return Tfinal`.

Comment: Never return a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration. An array defined inside a function without `static` has automatic storage duration. It “ceases to exist” when execution of the function ends. You will need to either allocate space with `malloc` and return that to the GUI software and arrange some way to deallocate the space when it is not needed anymore, or you will need to arrange for the GUI software to have space that it passes to your routine to be filled in with the temperature. Using a static array is another possibility but is bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return Tfinal;` has undefined behavior because you return the address of an array with local automatic storage. This array is discarded upon funtion return. Allocate the array with `malloc()` to return it to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

`Tfinal` is an array local to the function.  That means when you use `return Tfinal;` you're returning a pointer to the first element of the array.  So you're returning a pointer to a variable whose lifetime has ended.  Dereferencing such a pointer (or even reading it) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In contrast, `Vo` is defined at file scope and therefore has full program lifetime.

You need to either allocate memory dynamically and return that (and `free` the memory when you're done with it), declare the array `static` so its lifetime is that of the full program, or move the definition to file scope.